# Getting Rid of NA Values in One Array & Correlation in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm trying to correlate two arrays in R using the cor() function. However, I need them both to be the same length in order to compare them. The issue is, I'm getting my arrays from a larger data set, and there are NA values in one variable but not the other. I first subset the sample that I wanted from the larger data set, and now I'm trying to separate the variables into their own arrays and compare them. I'm able to get rid of the NA's from one of the variables, but that leaves the two arrays of different length.

Here's the code so far:

```
    ## Flight Differences in Distance

    SampleFlights <- subset(Jan2017DataSet, Jan2017DataSet$ORIGIN == 
    "LAX" & Jan2017DataSet$DISTANCE < 500)

    Dep_Delay <- c(SampleFlights$DEP_DELAY)
    Dist <- c(SampleFlights$DISTANCE)

    ##

    Dep_Delay <- Dep_Delay[!is.na(Dep_Delay)]

    cor(SampleFlights$DISTANCE, Dep_Delay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these values are taken from the same data frame, you can remove lines from the data frame prior to doing the correlation:

```
SampleFlights <- SampleFlights[!is.na(SampleFlights$DEP_DELAY),];
```

This also works with the `subset` operator:

```
SampleFlights <- subset(SampleFlights, !is.na(DEP_DELAY));
```

You can use `|` if you need to remove NA values that are present in either data set:

```
SampleFlights <- 
  subset(SampleFlights, !is.na(DEP_DELAY) | !is.na(DISTANCE));
```

And the correlation can be done without intermediate variable assignment:

```
cor(SampleFlights$DISTANCE, SampleFlights$DEP_DELAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the NAs in your first subset

```
     SampleFlights <- subset(Jan2017DataSet, Jan2017DataSet$ORIGIN == 
        "LAX" & Jan2017DataSet$DISTANCE < 500 & !is.na(Dep_Delay))
```

To find correlation you need your two variables to come from the same observation (flight) so you need to remove the entire row.